# Limiting the scope of glob qualifiers in zsh

Tags: zsh, wildcards

I'm almost certain that this is not something that the `zsh` shell provides a way of doing, but I thought I'd ask anyway just to make sure I'm not missing anything from the manual.

With the `zsh` shell, I can pick out the two largest visible files from a directory with the pattern

```
*(.OL[1,2])
```

If I have a set of directories, and I would want to have the two largest files from each, I believe I would have to loop over the individual directories and then use

```
$dirpath/*(.OL[1,2])
```

(where `$dirpath` is the directory path in the current iteration of the loop).

It would be *nice* to be able to say

```
*/*(.OL[1,2])
```

but that glob qualifier would apply to the list of matching names as a whole, and I would get two matches, not two from each directory.

Question: Would it be possible to limit the "scope" of the qualifier to only affect the most recent path component somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach could be something like:

```
print -rC1 -- *(N-/e['reply=($REPLY/*(N.OL[1,2]))'])
```

One can set the `$reply` array in the `e`xpression glob qualifier to further return a list of files. So here, we glob the list of dirs or symlinks to dirs and for each, return the 2 largest regular files.

Note that the `e` qualifier syntax is `e:code:`, where one can use other characters than `:` for the delimiter, or pairs like `e{code}`, `e[code]` (also `e(code)` and `e<code>` but those `(`, `)`, `<`, `>` would also need to be quoted). But note that word expansions are performed in the `code` part, actually anywhere in the glob qualifiers which is good because you can use variables in there like `*(L+$min_size)`, but here means you generally need to put the `code` inside single quotes to *prevent* the expansions.

Now, (and [it's a trick I learnt relatively recently](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2019/msg00725.html)) if instead of `:`, you use a character that happens to be wildcard character (which includes `?`, `*` but also the `[`, `]` pair) as the delimiter and leave the delimiters outside the quotes, then you don't need to worry whether that character may appear in the code, because an unquoted `*` delimiter can only be matched by another unquoted `*`, and same for `[` vs `]`.

So `*(N-/e['reply=($REPLY/*(N.OL[1,2]))'])` works even though `]` happens to occur within the (quoted) code delimited by unquoted `[...]`. It wouldn't work with other delimiters such as `:...:` or  `{...}`.

Comment: Yes, and the directory is passed in `$REPLY` into the `e` expression? Yes, this looks very much like what I was expecting when I set out, although Gilles' "brace expansion"-like solution was also good. I will have to turn it over for a bit to see what feels most natural to use.

Comment: Yes, this is the more natural fit for the way I'm thinking.

Comment: @Kusalananda. Personally, I generally use @Gilles's approach. Especially at the prompt, where I'd do `a=(*(/))`, possibly edit the array with `vared a`, and then reuse that array possibly several times with trial and error with `$^a`. Also note that using `e['reply(...)']` is hard to type and not much shorter than using the short loop forms `for f (*(/)) cmd -- $f/*...` (and in the end, that's just another form of loop so not much different).

Comment: Well, the syntax in your answer is ever so slightly more verbose, but it it's more in line with my way of thinking about what I need to do (and it's also a good example of use of the `e` qualifier). I will leave your answer as the accepted one and will possibly revisit later.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a loop. An intermediate variable is enough. Use the [`^` parameter expansion sigil](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) to distribute over the array.

```
dirpath=(*(N-/))
print -rC1 -- $^dirpath/*(.NOL[1,2])
```

Or you can use an anonymous function to avoid the temporary variable (which becomes `$argv`/`$@` the anonymous function arguments):

```
() {print -rC1 -- $^@/*(.NOL[1,2])} *(N-/)
```

Comment: Thanking you graciously for this!